# Why does this semantically identical class cause an undefined method 'new' error?

Tags: ruby, constructor

Why does the following code error:

```
class Complex
    def initialize(real, imaginary)
        @imaginary = imaginary
        @real = real
    end     
end

c = Complex.new(5,3)
```

> Complex.rb:8:in `<main>': undefined method`new' for Complex:Class
>   (NoMethodError)

but the semantically identical program below does not:

```
class Wat
    def initialize(a, b)
        @a = a
        @b = b
    end     
end

c = Wat.new(5,3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Complex` already exists, and is built in a different way, e.g.,

```
Complex(2, 3)
```

When you re-open a class (not defining your own) you operate under the existing class's constraints.

`new` was removed somewhere around 1.9 IIRC.

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Complex.html
- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Complex.html
- http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Complex.html
- http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/complex/rdoc/Complex.html

Comment: `Complex(2,3)` is a call to the [`Kernel#Complex`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Complex) method, that's a bog standard method with an odd name. The real problem seems to be that the `Complex.new` method was removed.

Comment: @muistooshort Yep. I didn't dig too deep into the "why", although I'm curious. I assume it's an "optimization" ;)